# Unable to setup multi node cluster

Tags: snappydata

I am trying to setup multi node cluster of [snappy data](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/install/install_on_premise/#machine-shared-path)

locator config :

```
a.com -dir=/snappydatafiles/server1 -heap-size=7096m -locators=b.com:8888,a.com:9999
b.com -dir=/snappydatafiles/server2 -heap-size=7096m -locators=b.com:8888,a.com:9999
```

server config:

```
a.com -dir=/snappydatafiles/server1 -heap-size=7096m -locators=b.com:8888,a.com:9999
b.com -dir=/snappydatafiles/server2 -heap-size=7096m -locators=b.com:8888,a.com:9999
```

lead config :

```
a.com -heap-size=2096m -spark.ui.port=9090 -locators=b.com:8888,a.com:9999 -spark.executor.cores=8
```

It is giving this error when I run using `/sbin/snappy-start-all.sh` or `bash /sbin/snappy-start-all.sh`:

```
a.com: Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
a.com: export: Command not found.
a.com: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
a.com: perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
a.com:  LANGUAGE = (unset),
a.com:  LC_ALL = (unset),
a.com:  LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
a.com:  LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
a.com:     are supported and installed on your system.
a.com: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
a.com: opendir(/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh/..): Not a directory at -e line 1
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 33: ./snappy-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 34: ./spark-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 37: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 38: /bin/load-snappy-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 44: /bin/snappy: No such file or directory
b.com: Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
b.com: export: Command not found.
b.com: export: Command not found.
b.com: opendir(/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh/..): Not a directory at -e line 1
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 33: ./snappy-config.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 34: ./spark-config.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 37: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 38: /bin/load-snappy-env.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-locator.sh: line 44: /bin/snappy: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
a.com: Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
a.com: export: Command not found.
a.com: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
a.com: perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
a.com:  LANGUAGE = (unset),
a.com:  LC_ALL = (unset),
a.com:  LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
a.com:  LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
a.com:     are supported and installed on your system.
a.com: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
a.com: opendir(/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh/..): Not a directory at -e line 1
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 33: ./snappy-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 34: ./spark-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 36: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 37: /bin/load-snappy-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 43: /bin/snappy: No such file or directory
b.com: Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
b.com: export: Command not found.
b.com: export: Command not found.
b.com: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
b.com: perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
b.com:  LANGUAGE = (unset),
b.com:  LC_ALL = (unset),
b.com:  LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
b.com:  LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
b.com:     are supported and installed on your system.
b.com: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
b.com: opendir(/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh/..): Not a directory at -e line 1
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 33: ./snappy-config.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 34: ./spark-config.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 36: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 37: /bin/load-snappy-env.sh: No such file or directory
b.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-server.sh: line 43: /bin/snappy: No such file or directory

a.com: opendir(/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh/..): Not a directory at -e line 1
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh: line 33: ./snappy-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh: line 34: ./spark-config.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh: line 36: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh: line 37: /bin/load-snappy-env.sh: No such file or directory
a.com:/snappydata/snappydata-1.0.2.1-bin/sbin/snappy-lead.sh: line 43: /bin/snappy: No such file or directory
```

**Note:** when I replace hostname with localhost and run after set this path variable ( setenv SPARK_LOCAL_IP 127.0.0.1 )  it is running fine and all memebers are started.

Default environment is csh

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
```

Bash installation

```
ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 941880 Mar 22  2016 /bin/bash
ls -l /usr/bin/env
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Dec 13  2017 /usr/bin/env -> ../../bin/env
```

export command is not working if run  in normal terminal 
But in root terminal export command works.

Comment: Do you have bash installed? Check "ls -l /bin/bash" and "ls -l /usr/bin/env"

Comment: @Sumedh I have added details in post. bash it is installed but Default environment is csh. When I run using `bash /sbin/snappy-start-all.sh` it gives same error.